# How to get URI to route in Laravel5

Tags: laravel-5

When a user click 'Delete' button, following URI is generated

```
http://localhost:8888/item?id=32
```

in my **route.php** I used

```
Route::get('item/id={ID}','ItemsController@destroy');
```

But it doesn't get the input and delete the record. I have created my destroy method properly and when I give URI manually as

```
http://localhost:8888/item/id=32
```

it deletes the record.

Why Laravel doesn't capture **item?id=32**? How to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your route matches URLs that start with "item/id=" and "item?id=" just doesn't contain this pattern.

Comment: yes, but how to make it into item?id=32? I also having the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the route to make this(*"http://localhost:8888/item?id=32"*) working, you can try the following:

```
Route::get('item','ItemsController@destroy');
```

and receive the id in the controller, by doing following things:

```
$id = Input::get('id');
// then do whatever you want for this id.. here Destroy
```

> Second way

If you want to make *"http://localhost:8888/item/id=32"* working, then you have to change the delete link. Make the link like the below one:

```
'http://localhost:8888/item/id=' + {IdWillBePlacedHere}
```

Comment: your answer is not about the issue. when button is clicked that link is generated.

Comment: @Sachith - It **is** about the issue. OP is trying to use the request path to fetch something from the query string, and Laravel's router does not see the query string.